# Can't connect to Postgresql on port 5432

Tags: postgresql, ssh, port, remote-access

I have PostgreSQL 9.3 installed on a server running Ubuntu Server 14.04.

If I ssh into the server via terminal, I'm able to connect with psql. But when I try to configure pgAdmin III to do the remote connection, I get:

> Server doesn't listen The server doesn't accept connections: the
>   connection library reports  could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused Is the server running on host "172.24.3.147" and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

When I run on the server `service postgresql status` it gives me:

```
9.3/main (port 5432): online
```

So of course I'm missing something important here.

EDIT

When running `netstat -na` on the server, I get (relevant portion, I guess):

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 172.24.3.147:22         172.24.3.240:61950      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.24.3.147:22         172.24.3.240:60214      ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: you didn't bind to that ip. pg's listening on something else, like maybe just 127.0.0.1:5432

Comment: What do you mean 'bind'? I'm using the port of the server (used in ssh), when I try to connect via pgAdmin.

Comment: you have to tell pg what interface/ip to listen to for connections. if it bound to only 127.0.0.1:5432, then any attempts on 172.24.3.147:5432 won't work, because nothing is listening for that ip:port combo

Comment: Per your comment, it should be reading on port 22 (why, if the default is 5432?), right? (That's what's in the State=ESTABLISHED line above). But when I try to connect to that port on pgAdmin, I get a different error: "An error has occurred: 14:57:13: Error: Error connecting to the server: SSL error: unknown protocol expected authentication request from server, but received S"

Comment: port 22 is ssh, and has nothing to do with postgres.

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74163070/14591547

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You have to edit **postgresql.conf** file and change line with 'listen_addresses'.

This file you can find in the `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main` directory.

Default Ubuntu config have allowed only localhost (or 127.0.0.1) interface, which is sufficient for using, when every PostgreSQL client work on the same computer, as PostgreSQL server. If you want connect PostgreSQL server from other computers, you have change this config line in this way:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Then you have edit **pg_hba.conf** file, too. In this file you have set, from which computers you can connect to this server and what method of authentication you can use. Usually you will need similar line:

```
host    all         all         192.168.1.0/24        md5
```

Please, read comments in this file...

### EDIT:

After the editing `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` you have to restart postgresql server: `sudo service postgresql restart`

EDIT2: Highlited configuration files.

Comment: Is "192.168.1.0" the remote server connecting to the Postgres DB? Why port 24?

Comment: @ScottSkiles 192.168.1.0 is address of network, /24 is not a number of port, but length of network mask in bites (255.255.255.0). In the other words: Allowed are computers from network 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0, having addresses from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254

Comment: So a single IP would be (for 192.168.1.1): 192.168.1.1/1?

Comment: @ScottSkiles single ip would be 192.168.1.1/32

Comment: Which file are you talking about? There are at least 5 conf files.

Comment: @Sören In my answer you can find at least two files, which you have to change.

Comment: You explained it all correct, but still I was making some common mistakes which I posted here..  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61182904/1005741

Comment: Pls I'm using google cloud shell editor and Postgres V13, however when I make changes to the postgresql.conf file, I can't save those changes, The save action never takes effect. When I try to open the file from terminal, I get prompted that edits are only allowed for files in the home directory. How do I change and save the postgresql.conf file in cloud shell?

Comment: @Urchboy Changes in file postgresql.conf can make only root or user postgres.

Comment: How would this go for the IPV6 line beneath the IPV4 line in pg_hba.conf for a specific individual machine?

Comment: @thefonso You can use, for example, `fe80::7a31:c1ff:abcd:abcd/128` instead of IP address and netmask. But there is a problem with IPv6 address privacy (autogenerated address). If you have static IPv6 address, it will works.

Answer (score 44):

> **Uncomment the listen_addresses = '*' in the postgresql.conf**

This has bitten me a second time so I thought might be worth mentioning. The line listen_addresses = '*' in the postgresql.conf is by default commented. Be sure to uncomment (remove the pound sign, # at the beginning) it after updating otherwise, remote connections will continue to be blocked.

PS: `psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'` - to locate the postgresql.conf file path

Answer (score 14):

just summary from the accepted answer

if maybe someone like me overlook the filename that must be edit

in my case the conf file located at

`/etc/postgresql/14/main'`

if you type `cd /etc/postgresql/14/main`

so just `sudo nano`  add these 2 filenames

1. **postgresql.conf**

`listen_addresses = '*'`

uncomment this line and change localhost to *

2. **pg_hba.conf**

`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0`

change the 127.0.0.1/32 change to 0.0.0.0/0

last don't forget to restart using `sudo service postgresql restart`

I hope this one clears the notification error

Comment: doesnt help with my connection refused...

Comment: Did you use md5 after specifiying the IP?

Comment: This is allowing connections from anywhere, I wouldn't recommend allowing all in pg_hba.conf

Comment: upvoting for reminding me to restart the service....!

Answer (score 9):

Remember to check firewall settings as well. after checking and double-checking my `pg_hba.conf` and `postgres.conf` files I finally found out that my firewall was overriding everything and therefore blocking connections

Comment: Your solution works for me.  I ran '`sudo ufw status` and saw that my firewall was blocking the connection to port 5432 because it was not part of the allowed list of ports. To fix the issue run `sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp`

Answer (score 8):

Had same problem with psql via command line connecting and pgAdmin not connecting on RDS with AWS.  I did have my RDS set to Publicly Accessible. I made sure my ACL and security groups were wide open and still problem so, I did the following:
`sudo find . -name *.conf`
then `sudo nano ./data/pg_hba.conf`
then added to top of directives in pg_hba.conf file `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`
and pgAdmin automatically logged me in.

This also worked in pg_hba.conf file
`host all all md5` without any IP address and this also worked with my IP address `host all all <myip>/32 md5`

As a side note, my RDS was in my default VPC.  I had an identical RDS instance in my non-default VPC with identical security group, ACL and security group settings to my default VPC and I could not get it to work.  Not sure why but, that's for another day.

Answer (score 8):

You have to edit `pg_hba.conf` to accept all requests within the network

```
#TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD 
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0                md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                  md5
```

From your application, you can connect using this IP address like below example: -

> postgresql://postgres:******@192.168.1.101:5432/app

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to either open up the port to access it in your LAN (or outside of it) or bind the network address to the port (make PostgreSQL listen on your LAN instead of just on localhost)

Comment: Sorry, as a lifetime PC developer, I'm not entirely familiar with this port thing. Right now I only need to access it inside our LAN (a proxy-based institutional network). The remaining of your message is unintelligible to me. See the other comments, please.

Comment: The answer by Jan Marek should be what you are looking for. `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     ` this line shows that Postgre's only listening for connection coming from the same computer where postgre is running, and not from the local network.

Comment: All right. But how do you guys know that the selected line is about Postgres? Because 5432 is their default port number?

Comment: Correct. It only shows two ports, 22 which is the default one for SSH, and you already mentioned that you are using SSH, and 5432 which is the default one for Postgres, which you mentioned that you are using and having issues with.

Answer (score 3):

If error occurred first thing first you have to read the log.

- This only applicable for postgresql installation through brew on your mac *

First, you have to check the postgresql status by running

`brew services` on your terminal

If its stopped, try to started it and then run the `brew services` again

And if the status show error, you can easily find the log location through the *.plist file.

Example, on my configuration

```
cat /Users/drosanda/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin/postgres</string>
        <string>-D</string>
        <string>/usr/local/var/postgresql@12</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/postgresql@12.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/postgresql@12.log</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is the log file content:

`2021-11-30 09:07:20.154 WIB [3891] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists`

`2021-11-30 09:07:20.154 WIB [3891] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 422) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgresql@12"?`

For my case, the postgresql won't start caused by the PID file is still exists.

It's easy to fix, by removed the `postmaster.pid` file.

Just add an answer that might useful for someone later.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after a MacOS system upgrade. Solved it by upgrading the postgres with brew.
Details: it looks like the system was trying to access Postgres 11 using older Postgres 10 settings. I'm sure it was my mistake somewhere in the past, but luckily it all got sorted out with the upgrade above.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. I originally installed version 10 because that was the default install with Ubuntu 18.04. I later upgraded to 13.2 because I wanted the latest version. I made all the config modifications, but it was still just binging to 1207.0.0.1 and then I thought - maybe it is looking at the config files for version 10. I modified those and restarted the postgres service. Bingo! It was binding to 0.0.0.0

I will need to completely remove 10 and ensure that I am forcing the service to run under version 13.2, so if you upgraded from another version, try updating the other config files in that older directory.

Comment: Had the same issue as well. I had upgraded my version of PostgreSQL and turns out editing the old version's config was the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

adding an updated answer for another possibility.  running postgres 10 on AWS EC2 I had to add a custom inbound rule through Windows Defender Firewall to allow port 5432.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else coming from docker and other applications issues like node js or Django or anything

i faced this problem for 2 days or more watched videos tutorials nothing seem to work although ill say i have missed some but here is the solution that worked for me

instead of local host for PGHOST

you must specify your service name

e.g

```
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgresdb
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./env/.env
    volumes:
```

then your host must be
PGHOST:nodeapp-db

Answer (score 2):

> If you have tried to edit **pg_hba.conf** and **postgres.conf** files
> as suggested above and nothing worked, then here you go !

## A try for the late birds: | LINUX USERS

After trying all other options suggested above, none worked for me.

So I released that this was happening due to failed **PostgreSQL Cluster 14-main** when booting/starting.

I followed below steps,

### Applied Solution :

1. `sudo chmod 700 -R /var/lib/postgresql/14/main`
2. `sudo -i -u postgres`
3. `/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl restart -D /var/lib/postgresql/14/main`

Note: You can replace 14 with your postgresql version number, you can check `/usr/lib/postgresql`/{mark the number you see here}

### After Solution status :

> pg_ctl: PID file "/var/lib/postgresql/14/main/postmaster.pid" does not
> exist Is server running? trying to start server anyway waiting for
> server to start....2022-11-17 13:06:36.614 CET [5542] LOG:  starting
> PostgreSQL 14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
> compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, 64-bit 2022-11-17
> 13:06:36.614 CET [5542] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0",
> port 5432 2022-11-17 13:06:36.614 CET [5542] LOG:  listening on IPv6
> address "::", port 5432 2022-11-17 13:06:36.616 CET [5542] LOG:
> listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
> 2022-11-17 13:06:36.623 CET [5543] LOG:  database system was shut down
> at 2022-11-17 09:20:13 CET 2022-11-17 13:06:36.631 CET [5542] LOG:
> **database system is ready to accept connections  done server started**

4. `pg_lsclusters`

Ver | Cluster | Port | Status |  Owner | Data directory |  Log file

10   main      5432    online   postgres  /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log

Finally, I was able to connect to **PORT = 5432** with no problem and everything worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

> windows === press WIN + R  //open services
> type - services.msc
> find postgres - double click on it.
>
> properties box open then click on start
> enjoy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just give one `sudo service postgresql start`

Answer (score 0):

I use home-brew to start my server.

1)*stop the server (but it is not working. it Is the problem)*

brew services stop postgresql

2)make update if it is needed

brew postgresql-upgrade-database

3)below comment solve my problem it start the server. Thats it

brew services start postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue and searches resulted in many complex overly solutions. Ultimately this issue was that a password had not been set after Postgres was installed on Ubuntu.

Solution:

1. From the Postgres terminal - reached by entering "`sudo -u postgres psql`" which should result in "`postgres=#`"...
2. Set the password using "`\password postgres`"
3. Update PG Admin with the new password and the username "`postgres`"

Reference https://www.cherryservers.com/blog/how-to-install-and-setup-postgresql-server-on-ubuntu-20-04.

Comment: For windows, "psql -U postgres" is all you need. My god it finally works. The password I made during installation finally gets me in. Wasted an hour on this stupid issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the server wasn't listenting because it didn't start up automatically (Windows version of PostgreSQL), because the setup program didn't create a user and didn't initialize the server. The following helped me:

After the setup I had to run (in a non-admin cmd.exe shell):

```
set PGDATA=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
createuser.exe -s postgres
pg_ctl init
pg_ctl start
```

After that, I used the `pgAdmin` tool and selected "Add new server" in the dashboard. There, I typed in the desired server name in the "General" tab, and in the "Connection" tab I entered `127.0.0.1` because I wanted to run it locally. After confirming it with <kbd>Save</kbd> it got created properly.

It seems that in Windows, Postgres isn't running as a Windows Service, so it doesn't start automatically and you have to run it manually. However you could create a `StartPg.cmd` file and put in the command `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_ctl start`, then you can open a Windows Explorer via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, enter `shell:Startup` in its path textbox (then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and copy the batch file (or a shortcut of it) into it.

Then it will start up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I’m using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) and after migrating to a new machine using Apple’s [Migration Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204350) the db server was unavailable:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I tried

```
sudo port load postgresql14-server
```

but that didn’t work. Looking at the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql14-server.plist` file, though revealed two things:

```xml
<key>Disabled</key><true/>
```

and the actual start command

```xml
<string>--start-cmd</string>
<string>/opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql14-server/postgresql14-server.wrapper</string>
```

So, running the start command manually finally showed the issue:

```
> sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql14-server/postgresql14-server.wrapper start
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/opt/local/var/db/postgresql14/defaultdb/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
```

and indeed:

```
> sudo ls -la /opt/local/var/db/postgresql14/defaultdb/
total 60
drwx------ 26 postgres postgres   832 Jan 31 05:13 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 postgres postgres   128 Feb  5 12:31 ..
-rw-------  1      500 postgres     3 Nov  7  2021 PG_VERSION
drwx------ 22      500 postgres   704 Feb  4 10:37 base
drwx------ 60      500 postgres  1920 Feb  4 10:37 global
drwx------  2      500 postgres    64 Nov  7  2021 pg_commit_ts
...
-rw-------  1      500 postgres   105 Jan 31 05:13 postmaster.pid
```

The user id was messed up. Fix:

```
sudo chown -hR postgres /opt/local/var/db/postgresql14/defaultdb/
```

to set the owner of all files to `postgres`.

With that change, the server works:

```
> sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql14-server/postgresql14-server.wrapper start
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
waiting for server to start.... done
server started
> psql -U postgres -W -p 5432 -h localhost
Password: 
psql (14.6)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# 
\q
```