# psql: could not connect to server... Is the server running on host ... and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: postgresql, azure, tcp, azure-virtual-machine

I know this is a popular question.  I have tried everything suggested in similar [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432).   I am trying to connect remotely to a postgresql database on an azure windows server 2012 machine.   I have tried the following...

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

**Firewall**

> New inbound rule (firewall) protocols and ports > protocol type > TCP
>
> Local port > 5432 Remote port > All

**Grab IP of remote machine**

I copied from azure dashboard and also as indicated on top of remote desktop connection

[image]

**CMD from local machine**

Then from local machine tried the following.

```
psql -U postgres -h 13.xx.xx.xx
```

**Error message.**

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
>   (0x0000274C/10060)
>           Is the server running on host "13.xx.xx.xx" and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I am not sure what else should be done.

Comment: After you changed the `listen_addresses` and `pg_hba.conf` settings, did you *restart* Postgres? The pg_hba.conf changes only require a reload, but the `listen_addresses` change requires a restart. You can verify the change from Postgres by running `select current_setting('listen_addresses');`
You can check your pg_hba settings via `select * from pg_catalog.pg_hba_file_rules();` (if Azure is using PG10 that is)

Comment: Yes, you need restart psql. It it still does not work, it seems a firewall issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you modify configuration file, you need restart it. You could use `netstat -ant|findstr 5432` to check it. It should listen like below:

```
C:\Users\shui>netstat -ant|findstr 5432
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
```

It seems a firewall issue. You need open port 5432 on Azure NSG.

[image]

I test in my lab, it works for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you kind genius @Shengbao Shui - MSFT.  This was the missing piece.  This worked for me.