# could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pythonanywhere

it's my first project to publish with django
i try to publish my first project on python anywhere but it still not working and this is my error :
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'arena',
        'USER': 'arenadbuser',
        'PASSWORD': ,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post what have you tried so far? Or you want someone else to debug this for you? For example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432

Comment: Postgres is not free there: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Postgres and it does not seem like localhost is what you should be using: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/PostgresGettingStarted

Comment: i don't know that Postgres is not free ..
it's my first time to deploy project

Comment: if you have paid for the postgres option on PythonAnywhere, on the databases tab, you will see information on what your host and port should be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232137/github-action-docker-database-migration-fail

Comment: Hi @omarahmed friend,have you solved this issue finally ?

Comment: Hi @William ... no i deployed this project on "heroku" ..