# Even with listen_addresses ='*' in postgres, remote login is not working

Tags: postgresql

I want to login to postgres using remote host.

I have configured the postgresql.conf file with  listen_addresses ='*'

I have configured pg_hba.conf file with

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

But still I am unable to login and I see the following error

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -d sbtest -U postgres -W -h 10.54.48.59
Password: 
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "10.54.48.59" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
-bash-4.2$
```

There is not firewall on it
and the port 5432 is open

Comment: Did you restart the server? Did you remove the comment (`#`) at the beginning of the `listen_addresses` line?

Comment: The firewall doesn't need to be one that machine, just between the two of them.

Comment: Yes, I have removed the comment (#) at the beginning of the listen_addresses

Comment: I am having same problem. did you managed to figured it out?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue today and I was following the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38466547/1005741). after spending few hours, I found my two silly mistakes. In case it help the other..

1) You will see two keys `listen_address` and `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf` file. everytime I look at it, I was modifying the wrong key `listen_address = '*'` and then keep on restarting service, but i did not worked. the correct key to look for is plural one

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

2) In `pg_hba.conf` file, instead of adding new row, we need to ***modify*** the existing row which is pointing to `127.0.0.1` address. my mistake was, I was adding another row with

```
host    all      all      0.0.0.0/0     md5
```

[Check if the port is open](https://askubuntu.com/a/328293/370085) for all or only for localhost using

```
 sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

Comment: FWIW, adding the row worked for me — and this should be the expected behaviour since you may want to authorize several distinct IP ranges.