# Adding listen_address="*" makes my postgres stop working locally

Tags: postgresql

I want to login to my db both locally and also remotely through psql. My config is below-

```
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

When I add `listen_address="*"` , my postgres stops working

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
ubuntu@ip-172-31-77-60:~$ psql -U postgres -h localhost
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
```

I am running postgres12. How do I enable remote and local logins (psql and pgadmin?)
Removing  listen_address="*" and restarting fixes my postgres instance but pgadmin tells me it can't connect

I did follow this question [Even with listen_addresses ='*' in postgres, remote login is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101635/even-with-listen-addresses-in-postgres-remote-login-is-not-working) and changed the

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

to

```
host    all      all      0.0.0.0/0     md5
```

and I tried the plural `listen_addresses = '*'` but I am still stuck.

Comment: Change to `md5 ` from `peer` in line `local   all             all                                     peer` and try.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `listen_addresses = '*'` (plural) and restarting the database shouldn't disable local connections. Check the log files to see if there is any error. A wrong parameter in the `postgresql.conf` is enough to prevent a database to startup! e.g. PostgreSQL 13 on Ubuntu try:

```
cat /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log.1
```

There you will see with more details what is going on with your database.

I suspect that the database couldn't be started, and since you didn't see any error message yet, you're having the impression that is started and is not accepting any connection. Change the `postgresql.conf` to  `listen_addresses = '*'` and restart the database

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```