# ROR is unable to connect PostgreSQL could not connect to server: Permission denied; while console can connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, nginx

I have a `Ruby on Rails` application running on nginx server (application server is on Red Hat OS). The database is installed on another server (same OS: Red Hat). 
*From console of the application server*, I'm *able to connect to the database* using same db credentials as in application. But the *ruby application is not able to make a connection*. It is throwing error

The error log `/var/log/nginx/error.log` has below error message

```
stderr: 
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: Permission denied
      Is the server running on host "10.178.61.135" and accepting
      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
):
```

Also, to mention I'm able to run the `rake db:migrate` successfully

The `database.yml` file looks like below:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: applicationdatabase
  host: 10.178.61.135
  pool: 30
  port: 5432
  timeout: 10000
  username: dbuser
  password: dbpassword
```

On Database server the connection config `/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_hba.conf`:

```
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
host       all          all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Database privilege

```
 List of databases
    Name             |    Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |      Access privileges
---------------------+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------
 applicationdatabase | dbuser      | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/dbuser            +
                     |             |          |             |             | dbuser=CTc/dbuser
```

Other configs and versions

```
# Web app Server
nginx/1.10.1
Phusion passenger 5.0.29
Ruby 2.1.9
Rails 4.1.5
pg 0.17.1
RHEL 7.7

# DB Server
PostgreSQL 11.3
RHEL 7.7
```

Comment: Worth to mention, I read 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432 and the postgresql conf is as suggested in the post.

Comment: As suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused; I tried removing the PID file and rebooting the machines, but no luck

Comment: can try your pg_hba.conf `local   all             all                                     trust`
`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5` and `host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5`

Answer (score 0):

If 'psql' on the app server can connect but your application itself cannot, it sounds like something on the app server machine, like selinux or apparmor,  which controls which users or apps can use the network.