# Postgresql server setting up on Azure VM (Windows server 2022)

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server, postgresql-15

I have Azure VM with PostgreSql on it, and I can't connect to it.

1. I opened a port for TCP in my VM networking in the Azure portal. [port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKEoJ.png)
2. I have installed PostgreSQL on my VM.
3. listen_addresses = '*' was already set in postgresql.conf
4. At the end of pg_hba, I added this:

   ```
   host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
   ```

   ```
   host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
   ```
5. Also, with netstat -a I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRhlb.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EzOT.png)
6. additionally, I can access the PostgreSQL server in my VM (as localhost), and I restarted the service a few times.
7. as a result, I still can't connect to it from my (no VM) PC. I try it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrXhs.png).

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got results successfully like below:***

I Installed same PostgreSQL server like below:

[image]

Check  the ***status of the PostgreSQL*** using below commend:

`sudo systemctl status postgresql-15`

And try to disable `SELINUX` config file, to allow access to connecting  postgressql instance like below:

**`Sudo vi /etc/selinux/config`**

[image]

Check whether  firewall is active, and try to disable the firewall  like below:

```
sudo systemctl status firewalld
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
sudo systemctl disable firewalld
```

[image]

Make sure to allow the PostgreSQL connection, change the parameter ***listen_address*** make sure to remove `#` before and restart the sql

```
vi /var/lib/pgsql/15/data/postgresql.conf
```

[image]

Now When I try `psql -u username -h hostname` and add  client Ip to pg_hba.conf

```
vi /var/lib/pgsql/15/data/pg_hba.conf
```

[image]

And try to add client authentication, range of IP addresses will be able to access your postgres.

***Now, when I tried to login with postgresql in Azure vm it got connected successfully like below:***

[image]

***Reference***:

[ssh - Can't connect to Postgresql on port 5432](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432)

Comment: hmm maybe windows server is the reason. Someone should try it there haha. Thank you for the answer!