# Connection timed out when connecting to remote postgres server

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use a Red Hat VM as a remote Postgres server but I can not connect to it using the 5432 port. I can however ssh into it using MobaXTerm.

I am using postgres version 15.6 and have followed the solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432) to no avail.
I keep getting connection timed out.

My /var/lib/pgsql/data/**pg_hba.conf**:

[image]

and /var/lib/pgsql/data/**postgresql.conf**:

[image]

Using *ifconfig* returns:

[image: ifconfig]

and then I use Dbeaver to test the connection:

[image]

The funny thing is that I had done this before on my other computer on which I can also do the same setup and it all works fine. The files match but for some reason, it doesn't work on my main computer.

Any help is very much appreciated! I can post further information if needed!

Comment: You said you can only connect over ssh, but then you don't describe or show your ssh tunnel setup.  If you are trying to connect directly but a firewall blocks you, a connection timeout is the expected result.

Comment: I'd say that that is a network problem and off-topic.

Comment: @jjanes Not sure what you mean by ssh tunnel setup. I didn't change anything from the fresh install of red hat. I just connect to it using 192.168.1.74:22 with root username and it works.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Strange, is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: I am sure that there is a way to fix the problem, but I don't see the connection to software development.

Comment: I've tried to turn off my Windows firewall but still get the same result unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution!**

Postgres was not allowed as a service on **firewall-cmd**.

I found the solution by exploring the [thread here](https://serverfault.com/questions/789014/issues-configuring-firewall-rules-for-postgres-on-centos).

To check all services that are allowed I used the command:

```
firewall-cmd --list-services
```

...which displayed:

> cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh

Then I used the command:

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=postgresql
```

...after which listing the services again gave me:

> cockpit dhcpv6-client postgresql ssh

Now the connection is successful!

**P.S.**

To make the firewall allow Postgres permanently use:

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=postgresql --permanent
```